# Chromebook - changing Android version (emulator/ real device)

Tags: android, android-emulator, chromebook

I want to debug my app on ChromeOS with Android version > 7.
How can I achieve it?
I have an Acer Chromebook device, and I can also use the Android Studio emulators - but in all the cases, the Android version is 7.x.x
Is it possible to update the Android version on the real device/ update the Android image for the Chromebook at the AVD?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to change the Android version on a Chromebook. Your best bet is to run Android in an emulator.